# Full Text search - Text split into multiple documents

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I am new to elastic search and I wonder if elastic search could solve an issue for our requirements:

We have many books and we would like to store each book into smaller chucks/sections (let's say 500 words).  I am not sure how search would work if I search for a phrase, **'The boy is standing in a blue shirt'**. especially when it is split into multiple record/documents

1. document 1: ...The boy is standing document
2. document 2: in a blue shirt. ...

Is there a best practice to store such data?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good question and I'd be curious to hear some suggested approaches. From my current understanding, your best approach would be overlap between these documents, meaning each "chunk" would also contain fields that could contain text for the previous and following chunks

Comment: you could try nested field if you want to keep relationship between segments https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html if you don't need to rebuild a book from its segments you can use also parent/child field. For curiosity, why you should need this kind of approach?

Comment: @MikeMichaels we thought are overlapping but i think it would create lot of noise and especially when we will have millions of records.

Comment: @Lupanoide we will need to rebuild the books.  Each segment will give us an Segment ID which we will map to other processed data e.g. we could color the particularly segment if processed data has the same/similar text. Also, segment will give us consistent page size and easily loading of books in a low bandwidth areas.  There might be other reasons but I can think of these at this stage.

Comment: @SharePointer Ok, if you need also metadata of segments, like segmentID, you can use only or nested field or parent/child field. For the difference between them, you can read this post asnwers from elastic team members https://discuss.elastic.co/t/choosing-parent-child-vs-nested-document/6742/